# Открытие submenu по клику

Tags: javascript, html

Открываются все ul.catalog__submenu.
Как избежать этого, без создания новых классов. 
Прошу помощи с открытием по этапано submenu

```js
$(".catalog__open").on("click", function() {
  $(".catalog__submenu").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="catalog__open">1</a>
    <ul class="catalog__submenu" style="display:none">
      <li><a href="#">2</a>
        <ul class="catalog__submenu" style="display:none">
          <li><a href="#">2.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2.2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2.3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="catalog__open">7</a>
    <ul class="catalog__submenu" style="display:none">
      <li><a href="#">8</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">9</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">10</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: А Вам обязяательно открывать меню по клику? Если открывать просто по наведению, то можно обойтись и без jquery...

Comment: @РамазанАлисханов обязательно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если с минимальным изменением вашего кода, будет так:

```js
$(".catalog__open").on("click", function() {
  /* Определяем номер кликнутого меню */
  var x = $(this).index('.catalog__open');
  /* По тому же номеру открываем суб-меню */
  $( ".catalog__submenu:eq(" + x + ")" ).toggle();

  console.log(x);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="catalog__open">1</a>
    <ul class="catalog__submenu" style="display:none">
      <li><a href="#" class="catalog__open">2</a><!--сюда добавил еще класc__open-->
        <ul class="catalog__submenu" style="display:none">
          <li><a href="#">2.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2.2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2.3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="catalog__open">7</a>
    <ul class="catalog__submenu" style="display:none">
      <li><a href="#">8</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">9</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">10</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Если надо будет при клике на новый пункт - закрыть предыдущий, такой случай описан здесь (2-й пункт) → [JavaScript переключаемые вкладки - табы (и немного CSS)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/981934/javascript-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-css)